# can't mount json nodes to root

Tags: javascript, json

i am trying to create a json in javascript and am trying to mount the nodes as root but manage to put them in another node attached to the root. Here is my code:

```
var responseData = [];
responseData.push({"groups": groups});
```

and get a hierarchy like this:

[image]

i would like to have the "groups" node attached directly to the root array object, not encapsulated in another "0" node. Note that i need to do this in code, procedurally, not manually generating the string.

Comment: What library are you using to get the tree (or is this just your debugger's output?)

Comment: the code is pure JS. for tree display: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: This is just the way that [JSON Editor Online](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org) displays an array with objects inside of it.  Is the desired outcome in your actual JSON to have `[{"groups": yourGroups}]` (an array with the first element set to an object) or `["groups": yourGroups]` (an array with the attribute "groups" set on it).  JSON doesn't support the latter, just FYI.

Comment: @SeanVieira the desired is the latter

Answer (score 0):

An array is an indexed data structure. If you push an object onto an empty array then your object will be at index 0 of that array.

However, arrays are just objects. If you really want to add an instance variable to it, then you can assign your groups data to a new property on your array.

e.g.

```
var responseData = [];
responseData.groups = groups;
```

Comment: i've tried that already and it doesn't seem to work. something like '    responseData.testing = "AAAAA";' has no effect, i don't see 'testing' anywhere. @AlfredoDelgado

Comment: You want an object, not an array.
`var responseData = {};` notice the curly braces and not square ones.

Comment: Please create a code sample of what isn't working for you if you need more help: http://jsbin.com/?html,js,output